# Limitations of nonprofit edition?

Tags: appexchange, nonprofit-starter-pack

I'm hoping to sell my app to nonprofits (1/2 price), but I'm not sure how to test it on a nonprofit org. It won't run on the Professional edition, so I'm worried about nonprofit edition.

How do others handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Nonprofit Success Pack is a [free](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5Gx6EAF) and [open source](https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/Cumulus) application. You can actually install the entire NPSP in a Developer Edition or a scratch org created with Enterprise shape to generate an environment like what your nonprofit customers will be using.

More than limitations of Salesforce edition, you may encounter challenges related to the unique way that the NPSP uses Salesforce. It is not a small customization layer! One of the biggest changes is the NPSP Account Model, which on newer installs is a Household model where every Contact is associated to an automatically-generated Household Account, with the NPSP's Affiliation object connecting it to any employers. The package also ships quite a lot of triggers, using a table-driven trigger management model.

Answer (score 1):

[Nonprofit Editions](http://www.salesforce.org/nonprofit_product/nonprofit-editions-pricing/) are a discounted version of Lightning Enterprise/Unlimited Editions, and have all the features you'd expect as an Enterprise Edition, including API access, Apex Code, and more. Please note that if you were to pass the Security Review, your application would probably work in Professional Edition anyways, with a few caveats, which is probably ideal if you intend to sell your package on the AppExchange.